# How to setup and use internal Maven repository?

Tags: maven-2, maven

Good day, everyone.

I'm trying to setup an internal repository that I can share with some people within a local network with no access to the Internet. So far, I have setup Archiva in my local machine and point the repository to my ~/.m2/repository. I asked those people to setup their Maven settings.xml and add the following profile:

```
 <profile>
 <id>archiva</id>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>archiva</id>
   <url>http://mymachine:8087/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>
 <pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
   <id>archiva</id>
   <url>http://mymachine:8087/archiva/repository/internal/</url>
   <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </releases>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </pluginRepository>
 </pluginRepositories>
 </profile>
```

I've also asked them to set this profile as always active. However, when they try to generate a new Java project using `mvn archetype:generate`, they always get an error. I actually forgot what the error was but it had something to do with the goal. They can download the jars from Archiva but the generation still fails. I also gave them a copy of the archetype catalog but it's still failing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

> I have setup Archiva in my local machine and point the repository to my ~/.m2/repository

I think that this is a wrong idea. You mix two concepts together. Archiva is a foreign repository, while `~/.m2` is a local repository. They should be kept separately, even if the physical machine is the same.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that. My goal in pointing Archiva's repository to my local repository is to share my repository with the people in the company. I have many of the commonly used libraries in there so I thought it should be ok. I can't connect to the Internet when I join their network so I have to find a repository that I can share with them and I think my local should be sufficient.

Comment: The problem will surface when you download some artifact snapshot from apache repository (for example) and maven will place it in _local_ repository. In the next download session maven will incorrectly download the same artifact from your Archiva as if it was apache repo. And you won't understand why maven doesn't update your local repo from apache :)

Comment: Well, for my own development setup, I don't use Archiva at all. All I do is create a symbolic link to my local repository to be referenced by Archiva as its repository. I did this so that if the people I'm working with need new artifacts from the central repository, I can just pull those and they can just get those from my machine. I'm not sure how this can become an issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with archetypes? They are project templates, and you need to create an archetype project (and `mvn deploy` it to your server) so that they can initialize first. Then, they'll pull with code like,

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=edu.berkeley.cs.sketch -DarchetypeArtifactId=skalch-archetype2 ...
```

See full example at [ntung.com/mvn](http://ntung.com/mvn). I have an example of an archetype project [here](https://github.com/gatoatigrado/skalch-archetype) (github). They're pretty basic and easy to read. Note that the archetype project is a maven project itself, so the top level `pom.xml` is for the archetype, and the `src/main/resources/archetype-resources/pom.xml` is where you want to put your above code referencing your server.

Maybe you mean to type `archetype:create` instead of `archetype:generate`? See http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_setup_Maven if that's the case.

BTW, since Maven uses so many plugins, good luck getting it to work without an internet connection! You might try buildr instead.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how archetypes work but I know that's what to use to start a Maven project. And yes, that's `archetype:generate`. Maven says `create` is now deprecated. Is there a way for me to clone Maven archetypes so I can make those available for the guys in the company. Personally, it frustrates me that they can't use the Internet but then I have to find a way to help them. I could probably generate a new project and have them copy it but I think it's better if they can start from scratch.